# Generic List code with Iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, template, iterator

I was wondering if this implementation of generic list with iterator is correct. The code compiles and goes fine. What would you think shall I improve? (first time I post here, I'm scared).
I'm also concerned about the const correctness of the code.

Class node

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

template<typename K>
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(const Node<K>& x);
    void setKey(const K& x);
    void setNext(Node<K> * const & x);
    void setPrev(Node<K> * const & x);
    Node<K>* getNext() const;
    Node<K>* getPrev() const;
    void insertNode(Node<K>* const & nil);
    void removeNode(Node<K>* const & nil);
    K getKey() const;
    K& getKeyRef();
private:
    K key;
    Node<K>* next;
    Node<K>* prev;
};

template<typename K>
inline Node<K>::Node() {
    this->setNext(this);
    this->setPrev(this);
}

template<typename K>
inline Node<K>::Node(const Node<K>& x) {
    this->setKey(x.getKey());
    this->setPrev(x.getPrev());
    this->setNext(x.getNext());
}

template<typename K>
inline void Node<K>::setKey(const K& x) {
    this->key = x;
}

template<typename K>
inline void Node<K>::setNext(Node<K> * const & x) {
    this->next = x;
}

template<typename K>
inline void Node<K>::setPrev(Node<K> * const & x) {
    this->prev = x;
}

template<typename K>
inline Node<K>* Node<K>::getNext() const {
    return this->next;
}

template<typename K>
inline Node<K>* Node<K>::getPrev() const {
    return this->prev;
}

template<typename K>
inline K Node<K>::getKey() const {
    return this->key;
}

template<typename K>
inline K& Node<K>::getKeyRef() {
    return this->key;
}

template<typename K>
inline void Node<K>::insertNode(Node<K>* const & nil) {
    this->setPrev(nil->getPrev());
    this->setNext(nil);
    nil->getPrev()->setNext(this);
    nil->setPrev(this);
}

template<typename K>
inline void Node<K>::removeNode(Node<K>* const & nil) {
    Node<K> *prev, *next;
    if(this != nil) {
        prev = this->getPrev();
        next = this->getNext();
        prev->setNext(next);
        next->setPrev(prev);
    }
}

#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

Class list with nested iterator

```
#ifndef LIST_LIST_H_
#define LIST_LIST_H_

#include "list_node.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename K>
class List {
public:

    class Iterator;

    List();
    List(const List<K>& x);
    ~List();
    void insert(const K& x);
    List<K>::Iterator begin();
    List<K>::Iterator end();
    List<K>::Iterator search(K k);
    void remove(List<K>::Iterator it);
    Node<K>* getSentinel() const;

    class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator();
        Iterator(const List<K>& x);
        ~Iterator();
        Iterator(const Iterator& it);                   // Copy constructor
        List<K>::Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& it); // Assignment operator
        List<K>::Iterator& operator++();                   // Next element
        K& operator*();                    // Dereference
        bool operator==(const Iterator& o) const; // Comparison
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& o) const;
        void setCurrent(Node<K> * const & x);
        Node<K>* getCurr() const;
    private:
        Node<K> * curr;
    };

private:
    Node<K> *sentinel;
};

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::List() {
    this->sentinel = new Node<K>();
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::List(const List<K>& x) {
    Node<K>* curr = x.getSentinel()->getNext();
    while (curr != x.getSentinel()) {
        this->insert(curr->getKey());
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::~List() {
    Node<K> *curr, *nil;
    nil = this->getSentinel();
    curr = nil->getNext();
    while(curr != nil) {
        curr->removeNode(nil);
        delete curr;
        curr = nil->getNext();
    }
}

template<typename K>
inline void List<K>::insert(const K& x) {
    Node<K>* node = new Node<K>();
    Node<K>* nil = this->getSentinel();
    node->setKey(x);
    node->insertNode(nil);
}

template<typename K>
Node<K>* List<K>::getSentinel() const {
    return this->sentinel;
}

template<typename K>
inline typename List<K>::Iterator List<K>::begin() {
    List<K>::Iterator it(*this);
    ++it;
    return it;
}

template<typename K>
inline typename List<K>::Iterator List<K>::end() {
    return List<K>::Iterator(*this);
}

template<typename K>
inline typename List<K>::Iterator List<K>::search(K k) {
    List<K>::Iterator it(*this);
    for (it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == k)
            return it;
    }
    return it;
}

template<typename K>
inline void List<K>::remove(List<K>::Iterator it) {
    Node<K>* curr = it.getCurr();
    curr->removeNode(this->getSentinel());
    delete curr;
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::Iterator::Iterator() {
    this->setCurrent(0);
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::Iterator::Iterator(const List<K>& x) {
    this->setCurrent(x.getSentinel());
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::Iterator::~Iterator() {
    ;
}

template<typename K>
inline List<K>::Iterator::Iterator(const Iterator& it) {
    this->setCurrent(it.getCurr());
}

template<typename K>
inline typename List<K>::Iterator& List<K>::Iterator::operator =(
        const Iterator& it) {
    if (this != &it) {
        this->setCurrent(it.getCurr());
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename K>
inline typename List<K>::Iterator& List<K>::Iterator::operator ++() {
    this->setCurrent(this->getCurr()->getNext());
    return *this;
}

template<typename K>
inline K& List<K>::Iterator::operator *() {
    return this->getCurr()->getKeyRef();
}

template<typename K>
inline bool List<K>::Iterator::operator ==(const Iterator& o) const {
    return this->getCurr() == o.getCurr();
}

template<typename K>
inline bool List<K>::Iterator::operator!=(const Iterator& o) const {
    return !(*this == o);
}

template<typename K>
inline void List<K>::Iterator::setCurrent(Node<K>* const & x) {
    this->curr = x;
}

template<typename K>
inline Node<K>* List<K>::Iterator::getCurr() const {
    return this->curr;
}

#endif /* LIST_LIST_H_ */
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Who owns the nodes? The way the code is now, when the list gets destroyed, then all the contents will be leaked.

Comment: Good point... I'll fix that.

Comment: @RafaelLerm,  I've implemented a destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use consistent naming

The include guard says `#ifndef LIST_H` but the actual include says `#include "list_node.h"`.  It's not technically an error, but I'd suggest that changing the include guard to `#ifndef LIST_NODE_H_`.

### Fix the destructor

Right now there is a memory leak in the destructor.  You need to add `delete nil;` as  the last line.

### Don't expose class internals

The `getKeyRef()` is a dangerous function because it essentially returns a handle to an internal data member of `Node`.  In fact, because all of the private data members have functions which "leak" their internals, I'd suggest making `Node` a `struct` and then making it a private within the `List` class.

### Avoid cluttering the code with `this->`

All of the instances of `this->` are just visual noise and don't really add anything to the program.  I'd recommend omitting all such instances.

### Eliminate unneeded functions

The `getSentinel()` routine, it seems to me, is probably only useful within the `List` class, so I'd recommend eliminating the routine and simply using the `sentinel` member variable instead.  Similarly, `Iterator::setCurrent()` and `Iterator::getCurr()` seem unnecessary.  I'd also recommend omitting `~Iterator()` since it literally does nothing.

### Rethink variable names

The variables `next` and `prev` and `key` are good names because they suggest how they are used.  However, `nil` and `sentinel` are not as good, in my view.  In some languages `nil` is the equivalent to `nullptr` and it seems to me that instead of `sentinel`, a better name might be `root`.  Also, I'd suggest that having `root` be a default-constructed `Node` instead of a pointer would simplify this class.

### Consider a different constructor

The `Node` class could benefit from a constructor like this:

```
Node(const T& value, Node *prev_=nullptr, Node *next_=nullptr) : 
    key{value}, prev{prev_}, next{next_} 
{}
```

### Simplify the `insert` code

Removing the functions from `Node` and making it a `struct` internal to `List` allows a much simplified `insert` routine.  For example, here's how the `Node` might look:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node {
    Node(const T& value) :
        key{value}, prev{this}, next{this} 
    {}
    Node(const T& value, Node *p, Node *n) :
        key{value}, prev{p}, next{n} 
    {}
    T key;
    Node<T> *prev;
    Node<T> *next;
};
```

This allows the `insert` routine to be written like this:

```
template<typename K>
inline void List<K>::insert(const K& x) {
    auto tail = root.prev;
    root.prev = tail->next = new Node<K>(x, tail, &root);
}
```

This also assumes that the previous few changes have also been made.

### Use `nullptr` rather than `0`

Instead of `this->setCurrent(0);`, it would be better to use `setCurrent(nullptr);` or simply `curr = nullptr;`.  While they result in the same thing, using `nullptr` makes the context and intent much more clear.

### Consider implementing a bidirectional iterator

Since your `List` is a doubly-linked list, it should be relatively simple to provide a [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) instead of just the forward iterator that is currently implemented.

### Consider adding a construct that uses `std::initializer_list`

It would be nice to be able to instantiate a list like this:

```
List<std::string> mylist{"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"};
```

This can be relatively easily added using the C++11 [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: "a default-constructed Node" - Then `Key` would need to be default constructible as well. And also copyable if one wants to be able copy the `List`.

Comment: I'll wait some more suggestion from you then before starting to apply them.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more complete.

Comment: @Edward, I'm sorry if I'm being too picky.

Comment: @Incomputable: We *all* benefit from that -- carry on!

Comment: @Edward, no need to be sorry. I'm trying to really improve my programming/software engineering skills. Shall I keep updating my code here? To code is stored in a GitHub repository.

Comment: @user8469759, if you want to get review on new code, then it would be better to post a follow up question. If not, you can post a selfie answer, but it should be full blown review. Changing code (even adding code), is discouraged after receiving answers.

Comment: Why would you declare the Node class as internal class/struct? What's the benefit of that?

Comment: The advantage of making it an internal class is that only the `List` class needs to or ought to have access to the `Node` class.  Users of the `List` need not use or even be aware of the existence of a `Node` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since Edward covered almost everything, I had to be extra picky about everything, e.g. going into `-WeverythingPossible` mode.

**Bugs:**

```
Node<K>* node = new Node<K>();
```

The line default constructs `K`, which is actually wrong. It should directly initialize underlying key with passed reference. As a result, if copying in `setKey()` will throw, the list will leak memory, e.g. the function doesn't have even basic exception guarantee. Exceptions problem apply to copy constructor as well, since it depends on `insert()` being correctly working.

**Redundant code:**

Inlining everything usually won't make a difference. It is a hint to the compiler, and mostly compilers ignore those hints.

**Missing functionality:**

- no `operator*` for const iterators.
- no reference in `search(K k)`, it should be `const K&`. In fact, `std::find()` already does the job, so the function is redundant.
- No emplace
- No move constructor+assignment
- No exception specification.
- No post increment
- other not so important stuff

**Coding style:**

Usually binary operators, like `!=`, `==`, etc, are implemented as free functions, `friend`s if needed. The motivation is that if they want to extend the functionality, they can't provide foreign type as a left hand side argument, since member equality and other operators work only if they are on the left.

Iterators usualy have private constructor and the container usually is a friend of it (thats what I use). I believe the motivation is that [iterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) doesn't require that, though there is no serious reason for that.

Not enough metaprogramming. Real `std::list` doesn't try to compile copy constructor if the `K` is not copy constructible.

**Some thoughts:**

When writing C++ code, I don't feel like I'm enjoying a walk in a park, but rather feel like I'm in a midst of a battle which turns into bloodbath. It becomes very dangerous to let guard down. Also, always keep compiler warnings at very high, but not `-Weverything`, since it brings some very unnecessary stuff, like C++98 compatibility. The usual flags are like what @Edward said, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14`, but if you have new compiler, it is possible to write `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: I absolutely agree that turning up the warnings helps to avoid writing faulty code. My default compiler settings for clang and gcc are `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14`.

Comment: @Incomputable, is `Node<K> *nil` equal to `Node<K> * const& nil`? I thought they were different.

Comment: @user8469759, the effect is the same. What you meant by `Node<K> * const&`? Reference to a const pointer pointing to non const object? Then true, otherwise not. Also, passing built in types as const references don't make much sense, since they are very cheap to copy. There are also implementation details about references, but I will leave them to discover in the future.

Comment: @Incomputable, I meant exactly that I pass a pointer and I want to be able to change the value of the pointed variable, but not the value of the pointer. Like if `a` points to `b` that stores `c` I want to be able to change the `c` value but not the `b` value (because that's actually what I need to do).

Comment: @user8469759, I see what you mean now. Just didn't see it used anywhere before (usually people would just pass it as plain reference, or use constructor for that or let list do that). Its just that I'm used to plain `struct`s to do that kind of stuff. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using std::unique_ptr to avoid handling memory leakage issues. new and delete are error prone.

Comment: Hi, I've never used std::unique_ptr, in a nutshell what would be the benefit in my code?